# Which preposition to chose with the infinitive?

Tags: prépositions, infinitif

Why do we say "Je suis obligé DE quitter" and at the same time "Il m'oblige A quitter"?

What is the rule about these prepositions? Is there anything special about prepositions with participles?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the rule is *être (adjectif / participe passé) de (infinitif)* with very few exceptions (e.g., *être prêt à*).

Verbs like *obliger*, on the other hand, don't have a nice, neat rule like that. You have to learn which [verbs take *à*](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-with-a/), which [verbs take *de*](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-with-de/), etc.